# Flexbox generator does not display well in my react application

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, flexbox, react-native-web

I am testing https://yogalayout.com/playground and have created that template:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

export default class MyLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      }}>
        <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
        }} />
        <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          backgroundColor: 'green',
        }} />
        <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          backgroundColor: 'purple',
        }} />
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

I expect to have this result:

[image: flexbox normal]

Instead, I have this:

[image: flexbox broken]

What could have break my flexbox layout?

Comment: Add ```flexDirection: "row"``` to your parent view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `flexDirection` is `column` in React Native. So, try setting it to `row` in your container `View`.

```
<View style={{
        flex: 1,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        flexDirection: "row"
      }}>
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it is different from the default browser behavior?

Comment: It is more convenient for mobile development. @EmielZuurbier

Comment: I was already testing in web, not in native, so this can't be the answer. Or you sure that default or different? (source?)

Comment: "so this can't be the answer" Have you tried it? @DimitriKopriwa

Comment: That was it. Thanks!